# Error: Apostrophe not preceded by \ (in and failed to execute aapt

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm creating an Android App using IntelliJ, and, on restart program.
I'm getting this error:

[Error](http://prntscr.com/ef66dv)

[Values.xml](http://prntscr.com/ef66t3)

And I'm having other problem: "Cannot resolve symbol R"

Comment: Error is self explanatory. Add a `\\` before all the apostrophes to escape them.

Comment: What apostrophes?

Comment: In your values.xml file. For example, for a string `abc's`, it should be `<string name="x">abc\'s</string>` in your values.xml file.

Comment: read the error and apply the suggested fix. what else do you need?

Comment: Worked! Thanks soo much!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP didn't even try to understand the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an apostrophe in The King's Businers, just use `King\'s Businers` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As the apostrophe `'` is a special character in Android resource files to mark the beginning or end of a string. All instances of it *as punctuation* must be escaped by a backslash `\`. This is so the apostrophe can be parsed as a literal character instead of the start/end of a string. For example, you have the word `King's` that is unescaped, this needs to become `King\'s`.

As for `Cannot resolve symbol R`, can you post the relevant bit of code where it's happening? You can try to fix it by moving the carat to the red `R`, pressing `Alt + Enter` and selecting *Import Class*.

Comment: no. apostrophe is not special in xml. only `<>&` are considered special and need to be escaped in xml. also, escaping in xml is done using entities, with for example `&lt;`. this character being special is specific to android format, and the escaping is also specific to android.

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks for the clarification, updated answer. So in "normal" XML `"` and `'` are considered perfectly valid? Been a while since I've used XML over JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The line-break (\n) may be messing up the text for you. Try wrapping the content in the CDATA:

```
<string name="the_text">
    <![CDATA[
    A ton of text \n with the line down char
    ]]>        
</string>
```